# guidance on using the Dart Analyzer vistor pattern

Tags: dart, documentation, analyzer

I'm trying to build an obfuscator for Dart packages (as opposed to release builds).

As an example I need to change something like:

```dart
class Existing {
  void aMethod() {}
}
```

to

```dart
class axq234ad {
  void afakdadhd() {}
}
```

I'm looking at using the analyzer package.

I've had some small success such as this example:

```dart
import 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart';
import 'package:codemod_core/codemod_core.dart';

/// Suggestor that renames a class
class ClassRename extends GeneralizingAstVisitor<void>
    with AstVisitingSuggestor {
  ClassRename(this.existingClassName, this.newClassName);

  String existingClassName;
  String newClassName;

  bool isMatching(ClassDeclaration node) =>
      node.name.value() == existingClassName;


  // The actual class declaration
  @override
  void visitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclaration node) {
    if (isMatching(node)) {
      yieldPatch(newClassName, node.name.offset, node.name.end);
    }
    super.visitClassDeclaration(node);
  }

  /// A variable declaration that uses the class
  @override
  void visitVariableDeclaration(VariableDeclaration node) {
    if (node.runtimeType.toString() == existingClassName) {
      yieldPatch(newClassName, node.name.offset, node.name.end);
    }
    super.visitVariableDeclaration(node);
  }
}
```

The first visitor 'visitClassDeclaration' is working nicely but the second one doesn't give me ready access to the node that holds the class name.

I can possibly muddle through the problem but I really need some decent doco and examples.

I've had a look at the LSP but it doesn't appear to use analyzer so it wasn't much help.

So I guess the question is; is there any decent doco or examples on what nodes I need to visit or perhaps what each of the visit methods 'visit' so I don't have to keep guessing?